# Vue build error @babel/compat-data not found

Tags: javascript, vue.js, build, babeljs

I'm about to deploy a VueJS app and I'm having an error when I try to build. Never happened before in development. I set up the production environment today and just cloned the project. I guess that last Node, NPM and dependency versions have been installed and something is crashing. Babel business.

Anyone else having this error?

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors

error  in ./src/main.js

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: [BABEL] /home/alvarooncode/Workspace/wedwedweddings-client/src/main.js: Cannot find module '@babel/compat-data/corejs3-shipped-proposals'
```

and more...

I tried to install @babel/compat-data and after run `npm run build` no `img` directory is created. No errors in compilation but no images are released...

Any help, please.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

npm update --depth 5 @babel/compat-data